# IntelliJ IDEA 13 on Mac Line highlighting

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, highlighting

Getting a weird line highlight in some of my JSP files here:

[image]

Any ideas on how to disable this?

Comment: Does hovering over it show anything? Or is there any paired indicator in the gutter on the right side of the editor? It looks like the Darcula theme's default background color for injected languages, even though it doesn't look like there are any injected languages in the highlighted space.

Comment: Hovering does nothing, clicking the area highlights it with the same grey background as clicking any other line.

Comment: You might experiment with the color/font settings as indicated in z5h's answer, then.

Comment: Seems like it was treating the lines as injected code, removing the background from that removed the JSP background. Not sure why it was treating it like injected code though.

Comment: Perhaps try deleting those lines and manually re-writing them. Could be some strange edge case where an unprintable character is considered to be a marker of some sort for an injected language by IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

As well as foreground color, each syntax element can have a background color. It can also inherit attributes form other similar syntax elements. It looks like the background for tags is different than the background for other stuff.

Go to Preferences > Editor > Color & Fonts > JSP.
In the preview area, you should be able to click on an element and have the syntax settings for it come up. From here you are on your own. Look at the setting and set it up as you like.

Comment: An addendum: since the highlighting looks like what IntelliJ considers an injected language, the "Injected language fragment" setting is under Colors & Fonts > General.

Comment: None of them have the background as the green.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a regular HTML file that had IE conditional comments. Using @ajp15243's response, I duplicated the current theme, which allowed me to simply disable the background for `Injected language fragment`. Since I couldn't comment, I thought I'd post instead. =/ But the credit is all @ajp15243.